# Tomcat java options

Tags: tomcat

Где можно найти документацию по настройке Tomcat java options?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Более всего меня интересуют настройки, начинающиеся с `-D` и, в частности, настройка

```
-Dlog4j.debug
```

Где можно найти её описание? Что значит эта настройка, для чего она нужна?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Где можно найти документацию по настройке Tomcat java options?

Конечно же на первоисточнике http://tomcat.apache.org/. Документации на русском пока нет, только обрывки информации.

> Более всего меня интересуют настройки, начинающиеся с -D

Префикс -D означает настройка по умолчанию (Default).

> в частности, настройка -Dlog4j.debug

Вы можете включить -Dlog4j.debug для печати отладочной информации в поток System.out. По умолчанию Log4j ищет файл с именем log4j.properties или log4j.xml. Вы можете контролировать, какой файл он использует, чтобы инициализировать и настроить под себя Log4j.

Посмотрите обзац "Default Initialization under Tomcat" [(ref)](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).